# Firebird php Failed to locate host machine

Tags: php, firebird

I try to run an `ibase_connect` to an firebird database.

**The database is NOT on my localhost. It run on an network windows server.**

I have windows too and have an connection to the shared folder:

`Z:\Folder_WITH_DB.`

I have XAMPP installed with

- `ibase extension`
- `pdo firebird extension`.

I copied the **fbclient.dll** into my **XAMPP/php** folder.

But if i run this code:

```
$db = 'Z:/Folder_WITH_DB/database.fdb';
$username='SYSDBA';
$password='masterkey';

$dbh = ibase_connect ( $db, $username, $password ) or die ("error in db connect");
```

gives this error

```
 Warning: ibase_connect(): Unable to complete network request to host "Z". Failed to locate host machine. in xxx/index.php on line xx
```

**firebird.log**:

```
INET/INET_connect: gethostbyname (Z) failed, error code = 11004
```

I added `gds_db  3050/tcp` to the service file on my localhost and the server (have restarted both) and it is the same error.

Windows Firewall is deactivated on server. Service for firebird server and firebird guardian is running.

Comment: Did u try to do it with hostname instead? `\\SERVERNAME\Folder\db.fdb`

Comment: Same error :/ I tried it with the IP too.

Comment: Try changing the `share permissions` for the share to read&write for `everyone`?

Comment: for windows : `SERVERNAME:Z:\Folder_WITH_DB\database.fdb`

Comment: Permission is set for everyone. And `servername:z:` does not work :/ I have restarted the server too...

Comment: You can't use Firebird with a database from a shared folder, you need to connect to a Firebird server (with the database local to that server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird can only use a database file local to the database server. You can't connect to a Firebird database on a network share*. You need to connect to the Firebird server instead.

So if the database of 'Z:/Folder_WITH_DB/database.fdb' is on server firebirdsrv in folder D:\data\database.fdb, then you need to connect to `firebirdsrv/3050:D:\data\database.fdb`. I strongly suggest to remove the networkshare.

*: Technically a share can be used, but it is disabled by default because accessing a database from multiple servers through a network share can corrupt a database.